# Backbone.js Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'on'

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

Can anyone help me with this one? I don't know what's going wrong.

Getting data from a json file:

```
this.categoryTrees = new CategoryTrees();
this.categoryTrees.getCategoryTreesFromJSON();

this.categories = new Categories();
this.categories.getCategoriesFromJSON();
```

Creating views for it:

```
//view for startscreen
this.startscreenView = new StartscreenView({collection: this.categoryTrees});

//view for subjectsList
this.subjectsListView = new SubjectsListView({collection: this.categories.where({ category_tree : "onderwerpen" }) });
```

The second one with the where clause gives me an error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'on'

When I don't put up the where clause it works just fine. In console I am able to perform the where function without any problems.

Do I miss something here?

Comment: You need to post the classes for your two collections. Are they definitely Backbone Collections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`where` method](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where) will return **an array of all the models** in a collection that match the passed attributes.  So it doesn't return a `Backbone.Collection` so you get the `on` undefined error.

You need to create a new `Categories` collection from the result of the `where` with :

```
this.subjectsListView = new SubjectsListView({
    collection: new Categories(
        this.categories.where({ category_tree : "onderwerpen" })) 
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! But I need to perform the this.categories.getCategoriesFromJSON(); function before the where clause, as this function will return my categories. Creating a new collection without performing the function won't give me any results as the collection is not valid.

Comment: You can still call the `this.categories.getCategoriesFromJSON();` before the `where`. The point is that from the result what the `where` returns you need to create a new `Categories` collection which will contains exactly the items which where returned from the `where`. Have you actually tried my solution? Is it worked or you have got a different error?

Comment: Thank you. But I'm not getting that. When I do so my view is empty, and the collection shows an unfiltered array in console. I tried all combinations, but no result. 

    this.categories = new Categories();
    this.categories.getCategoriesFromJSON();

    this.subjectsListView = new SubjectsListView({
    collection: new Categories(
    this.categories.where({ parent : null })) 
    });

Comment: @MarV then please post your `getCategoriesFromJSON` method because creating a new collection should work fine. See also in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/WD8vD/ It would be also helpfull I could create a jsfiddle with your own code.

Comment: You're right. The function works fine. I've tested it with your getCategoriesFromJSON method, and then things are working fine. The where on my collection causes the problems. This is my method:

Comment: getCategoriesFromJSON : function(){
     var self = this,
      categories = [];

     $.ajax({
      url      : './catalogue.json',
      dataType : 'json'
     }).done(function(data){

      console.log('Catalogue retrieved');

      _.each(data.categories, function( categorieObj ){

       var categorieName       = _.keys(categorieObj)[0],
           categorieAttributes = categorieObj[categorieName];

       categories.push( categorieAttributes );
      });
      
      //console.log(JSON.stringify(categories));

      self.add( categories );
      self.trigger('reset');
     });

Comment: Addition: models looks empty but isn't, when i output to console

d {models: Array[0], length: 0, _byId: Object, constructor: function, model: function…}
_byId: Object
_events: Object
_idAttr: "id"
_listenerId: "l15"
length: 15
models: Array[15]
__proto__: e

Comment: @MarV: Your getCategoriesFromJSON function perform an ajax call so the result of this.categories only available later when the 'done' function executed. I suggest you put the code to create new category inside that 'done' function.

Comment: how do I do that, as i don't have my collection available in that function? Also tried to listen to reset and perform a render, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Found a proper solution. Before starting the backbone app I'm retrieving the JSON data in a new function loadDataAndStartApp(). This function is loaded when the dom is ready, and once the JSON is loaded it starts the backbone app. This way you are certain to have all the data available. Together with what nemesv said about creating a new categories function and al the other suggestions at his answer I worked out the following answer to this problem.

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
routes: {
    "": "startscreen",
    "Onderwerpen": "subjectsList"
},

initialize: function  (options) {


    this.categories = new Categories( options.categories );


    this.subjectsListView2 = new SubjectsListView({
        collection: new Categories(
            this.categories.where({ parent : null, name : "Evenwicht" })
        )
    });

    //view for spacesList



},

startscreen: function () {
    $('#app').html(this.startscreenView.render().el);
},

subjectsList: function () {
    $('#app').append(this.subjectsListView2.render().el);
},

});

function loadDataAndStartApp(){

var categories     = []

// LOAD APP DATA
$.ajax({

    url      : './catalogue.json',
    dataType : 'json'

}).done(function(data){

    console.log('Catalogue retrieved');

    // GET CATEGORIES
    _.each(data.categories, function( categorieObj ){

        var categorieName       = _.keys(categorieObj)[0],
            categorieAttributes = categorieObj[categorieName];

        categories.push( categorieAttributes );

    });

    // START APP
    var app = new AppRouter({ 
        categories     : categories
    });

    Backbone.history.start();
});
}


$(function(){
// ON DOM READY

loadDataAndStartApp();
});
```