# Access an array of models?

Tags: javascript

Im a little stuck, I am using backbone.js the code below returns an array of models see image below.

```
//The array of objects
var teamPlayers = this.players.where({team_id: team.get('id')})
```

`players` is a collection. Instead of saying `this.players.each(function(models){ //code here })` I want to say something like `teamPlayers.each(function(models){ //code here })`. So I can associate two collections matching their id's

[image]

I can do this successfully inside a template, but I need to separate my team views from my player views then render it in an app view.

Here is the template I am trying to achieve a result like this.

```
<script type="text/template" id="allTemplate">

    <% _.each(teams, function(team) { %>

            <div class="<%= team.name %>">

            <h1><%= team.name %></h1>

            <% var teamPlayers = _.where(players, {team_id: team.id}) %>

                <% _.each(teamPlayers, function(player) { %>
                    <li> <%= player.name %> </li>
                <% }); %>

            </div>

    <% }); %>


</script>
```

So I am trying to convert that template into javascript so that I can do a for each on the view.

**Extra:** here is what the each collection code looks like

```
this.teams.each(function(team) {
    var teamView = new TeamView({ model: team });
    var teamHtml = teamView.render().el;
    this.$el.append(teamHtml);

    var teamPlayers = this.players.where({team_id: team.get('id')})
    console.log(teamPlayers)

    this.players.each(function(player) {
        var playerView = new PlayerView({ model: player });

        var playerHtml = playerView.render().el;
        this.$el.append(playerHtml);
        console.log(player.toJSON());
    }, this);

}, this);
```

Edit: I just wanted to add I came across this [Backbone.js Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'on'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840243/backbone-js-uncaught-typeerror-object-object-array-has-no-method-on) it kind of makes sense but I cant figure out how to apply that answer to my project and the way I have created my pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_.where returns an array, not a Backbone.Collection, so turn:

```
this.players.each(function(player) {
```

into

```
_.each(teamPlayers, function(player) {
```

Comment: Oh wow, thanks dude! I adopted `this.players.each` from a tutorial. This worked, it's amazing how one little thing can throw all of your application off.